# Hide window created by WinAPI call

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, ghostscript

I'm trying to call GhostScript(GS) command line tool from C++ code. Unfortunately, GS creates window with progress bar. I was wondering is there a way to hide this window? Code listed below. I will be grateful for any advice.

```
std::string cmd = ("gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -sOutputFile=\"%printer%HPLJ2000\" \"1.pdf\"");
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
auto dwFlags = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;
STARTUPINFOW si;
GetStartupInfoW(&si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

if (!CreateProcess(NULL, cmd.c_str(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
    std::err << "Something went wrong" << std::endl;
}

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **is** in the documentation, look [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/Devices.htm#Win) under section 10.2 Supported Options (device properties)

> The following options are available:
>
> ```
> /NoCancel boolean
>     Disables (hides) the progress dialog when set to true or show the progress dialog if not set or set to false.
> ```